# Python - Loop through files and store occurrences by file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python script that I need to adapt, I have to open 4 different files and generate a final file that has the number of occurrences of a "word" for each file, for example:

Format: file - occurrences in file 1, occurrences in file 2, occurrences in file 3, occurrences in file 4

apple, 3,4,1,5
pineapple, 7,4,1,3

I want to do it without using external libraries. Initially, I have the idea of storing the values in lists and then adding them to the file but I don't see it performing. Currently the code for a single file I have it like this:

```
def data():
    list_words = []
    with open("story.txt") as words:
        for line in words:
            word = line.split()
            for i in range(len(word) + 1):
                if i not in list_words:
                    list_words.append(i)
                else: 
                    list_words[i] += 1
```

I did not find much relevant help in other posts, any ideas will be welcome, thanks!

Edit:
Example of how are the files that I must open and verify the words:

http://textfiles.com/stories/3lpigs.txt
http://textfiles.com/stories/adler.txt

They are txt files with stories

Comment: How does your file look like? Some samples would be helpful.

Comment: @DanielHao I just added the edit with the examples from the original files:
http://textfiles.com/stories/3lpigs.txt http://textfiles.com/stories/adler.txt
Thanks!

Comment: Here is a similar post - you can try to modify to suite your needs:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384673/python-word-count-program-from-txt-file

Comment: This question more or less asks what you are asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068959/count-of-specific-words-in-multiple-text-files/68077948#68077948

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count of Specific words in Multiple text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068959/count-of-specific-words-in-multiple-text-files)

Comment: One thing to note is - you've to check and clean the word by removing the possibly **punctuations**, before doing the  counting .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest word counter that uses the fact that dictionary keys are unique.

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog

master = tkinter.Tk()
master.withdraw()

def data( pathfilename ):

    word = dict()
    with open( pathfilename, mode='rt' ) as words:
        text = words.read()
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        for k in line.split():
            if k in [
                '', chr(10), chr(13), chr(9), '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';',
                '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '\\',
                '|', '<', '>', '/', '"', "'", chr(96), '~', '[', ']', '{', '}' ]:
                pass
            elif k in word:
                word[ k ] += 1
            else:
                word[ k ] = 1
    return word

fdir = filedialog.askopenfilename( title = 'Pick a txt file' )
if fdir:
    result = data( fdir )
    print( len( list( result.keys() ) ) )
    print()
    for k,v in result.items():
        print( f'{k} = {v}' )

master.destroy()
```

It returns a dictionary of words and counts.